# DDDD: Event data

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, dddd

I'm trying to get my head around **DDDD** in **Greg Young's style**.

There is much talk about how to implement **DDDD with CQRS+EventSourcing** and there are some sample implementations ... and altogether it can be quite confusing...

In Gregs view **aggregates don't have getters or setters** - just state-changing methods which emit an corresponding event.

Basicly a **event** decribes a **state-transitions** that happend in the past. It's data describes what changed.

Some say, that **this data can be "*enriched*" by additional data**.
***Where*** can this additional data come ***from***?

i.e. I have **`User`** and **`Usergroup`** - **both aggregate roots** (can exist independently, have identity). `User` has a method called `AddToUsergroup`.

```cs
public class User : AggregateRoot
{
    // ...
    public void AddToUsergroup(Usergroup usergroup)
    {
        // validate state
        RaiseEvent(new UserJoinedUsergroup(this.Id, usergroup.Id));
    }
    // ...
}

public class Usergroup : AggregateRoot
{
    private string _displayName;
    // ...
    public void ChangeDisplayName(string displayName)
    {
        // validate state
        RaiseEvent(new DisplayNameChanged(this.Id, displayName));
    }
    public void Apply(DisplayNameChanged e)
    {
        this._displayName = e.DisplayName;
    }
    // ...
}
```

If I would like to "**enrich**" the **event** with the **name of the Usergroup** (for debug reasons or something like this), how would I do that?

- **getters** are **nonexistent**
- **internal state** of usergroup is **inaccessible**

**Injecting** such things as **repositories** into `User` is **not allowed** (**am I right here?!?**), like

- Read-side repository
- Event-store repository

### Bottomline questions:

- <del>Can</del> Should something like **repositories** be ***injected*** to aggregate roots?
- Should a event ***only*** use **data available through parameters and internal state** of the aggregate?
- Should events ***only*** contain the ***minimum* data** describing the state-change?

And (little off-topic but the sample is here)

- Should `AddToUsergroup` take an **Guid** *instead* of an ***full* aggregate root**?

Looking forward to your answers!

Lg
warappa

Comment: I can help you with the off-topic question.. you should only pass the Guid to the method, not the aggregate root.

Comment: regarding the "bottom line questions". In my usage, the event should contain the minimum amount of information that is required by the business case. It should only contain data from the within the aggregate itself. ie: passed via the parameters or internal state.

Comment: @Sarmaad Thanks! You strengthened my presumption!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should something like repositories be injected to aggregate roots?

No and there is no need to in this case. It can be appropriate to pass a domain service to a behavioral method on an aggregate, but again, not needed in this case.

> Should a event only use data available through parameters and internal
>   state of the aggregate?

Yes, the original domain event should be such that it can be easily built by the aggregate and can be replayed in a deterministic fashion.

> Should events only contain the minimum data describing the
>   state-change?

Yes. However, to address requirements of external subscribers, this is where [content enricher](http://www.eaipatterns.com/DataEnricher.html) comes into play. To dispatch a domain event externally, it is first committed to the event store then you can dispatch in the same tx or have an out of process mechanism which publishes events externally. At the point of publishing externally, you will normally use a different contract for the message since subscribers may need more than what is on the domain event itself. In this case, you need the user group name. The publisher, then, can pull up the user group name and place that data into the enriched event. This publisher can have access to a read-model repository for user groups which would allow it to retrieve the name.

> Should AddToUsergroup take an Guid instead of an full aggregate root?

Yes. Passing the entire aggregate may not be possible and also creates the illusion that something other than the ID may be used, which should not be the case.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, especially the clarification on content enrichers!